# Loop over controls in another class

Tags: vb.net, winforms, oop

I have created one form with two datagridviews, two text boxes with some random text, and two combo boxes with some random text.

[image: datagridviewform]

I have created two classes. DataGridViewForm and DataGridViewClass

I loop over the controls on the DataGridViewForm to clear the controls

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' Pressing this button will clear all text and comboboxes
        Dim button As New DataGridViewClass()

        Dim a As Control = Nothing
        For Each a In Me.Controls
            button.Wissen = a
        Next            
    End Sub
```

and it the DataGridViewClass

```
    Property Wissen() As Control
        Get
            Return ControlName
        End Get
        Set(value As Control)
            ControlName = value
            If TypeOf ControlName Is TextBox Then
                ControlName.Text = Nothing
            ElseIf TypeOf ControlName Is ComboBox
                ControlName.Text = String.Empty
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
```

This works fine, but I would like to move the loop from the dgvFrom to the dgvClass. How would I do that? If I would move that loop I get the error "Controls is not a member of DataGridViewClass"

Okay, on the suggestion I tried this:

```
        ControlName = value
        Dim a As Control
        For Each a In ControlName.Controls
            If TypeOf a Is TextBox Then
                a.Text = Nothing
            ElseIf TypeOf a Is ComboBox
                a.Text = String.Empty
            End If
        Next
```

And in DataGridViewForm I put

```
Dim button As New DataGridViewClass()

button.Wissen = Me
```

This works! Now I can use the same Clear button for other forms. Thanks!

Comment: DataGridViewClass class needs a reference to DataGridViewForm, then you can do form.Controls from inside DataGridViewClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controls of `DataGridViewForm` are not static, you need to pass an instance of `DataGridViewForm` to an instance of `DataGridViewClass` and then `DataGridViewClass` will have access to all controls of `DataGridViewForm`, here is a basic example:

```
Public Class DataGridViewForm

    Private DgvClassObj As DataGridViewClass
    Sub New()
        ' pass this DataGridViewForm instance (Me) to an instance of DataGridViewClass
        Init()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Init()
        DgvClassObj = New DataGridViewClass(Me)
        DgvClassObj.SomeMethodToLoopOverDataGridViewFormControls()
    End Sub

End Class


Class DataGridViewClass

    Private DgFormObj As DataGridViewForm
    Sub New(ByRef dgform As DataGridViewForm)
        Me.DgFormObj = dgform
    End Sub

    Public Sub SomeMethodToLoopOverDataGridViewFormControls()

        For Each c As Control In DgFormObj.Controls
            ' now you can loop over the instance of your DataGridViewForm class
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for something like that. However, there will be other forms that will have the same button with the same functionality. So the form should pass it's name to the class in a variable.

Comment: not the name, the instance of the class as an object...  if that answer is answering your question please mark it as an answer.